# Напишите программу, которая по полному списку выдаст этот список в сокращенном виде

Tags: c++, любой-язык

Для данного списка различных чисел от 1 до N нужно построить сокращённый вариант списка: если подряд идут несколько номеров, то они заменяются на интервал через тире. Пример:

> 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,16,17,20,21,22,23,24

превращается в

> 1,3-8,10,12,16-17,20-24

Как реализовать это наиболее изящным способом?

Конкретный язык не важен, но лучше C++ или подобный ему.

Comment: И в чем же вопрос-то состоит?

Comment: Вы наверно перепутали сайт, это не фриланс.

Comment: Это не вопрос, а просьба :) Для данного сайта она очень далеко выходит за рамки...

Comment: Я думаю, в рамках гольфа этот вопрос допустим.

Answer (score 10):

Работает в Visual Studio 2015. Поддерживается длинная арифметика.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin >> s;

  cout << regex_replace
  (
    regex_replace
    (
      regex_replace
      (
        s,
        regex("\\d+\\b"),
        "$&#$&-$&"
      ) + "0123456789",
      regex("(\\b(?=9.*(1))|0(?=.*(1))|1(?=.*(2))|2(?=.*(3))|3(?=.*(4))|4(?=.*(5))|5(?=.*(6))|6(?=.*(7))|7(?=.*(8))|8(?=.*(9))|9(?=.*(0)))(?=9*-)|\\d{10}$"),
      "$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12"
    ),
    regex("(#(\\d+)-\\d+,\\2\\b)+#\\d+|#\\d+-\\d+"),
    ""
  ) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: И зачем здесь regex использовать? Тут на циклах сделать лучше.

Comment: @Alex78191, а тебе рейтинг вопроса в -12 не подсказывает, что нормально на него отвечать никто не хочет? А вот с регулярками поиграться интересно было - я их в плюсах почти не знаю.

Comment: К сожалению вопрос закрыт и не ответить на него

Comment: @Alex78191, хочешь переоткрыть?

Comment: Считаю, что причина закрытия указана неверно

Comment: Вот подходящая «Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»). Для повторного открытия вопроса, добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему.»
 Интересно, ведь не знаешь как реализовать это тоже проблема.

Comment: @Alex78191, на тот момент этого пункта не было)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59757/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alex78191).

Comment: https://ideone.com/TKskBU